# What do you call this type of animated graphic?

Tags: animation, gif, terminology

[image]

I am trying to make a bunch of images such as the one above to explain a part of my app. I would like to hire someone to make them for me but I am not sure what you call them. I have tried:

- animated gifs
- explainers

I would love to know what is the term professionals use.

Comment: I might go with a full sentence "I want to create an informative video about my application" ...and as for the type of video I want, I would explain by showing example(s) and then perhaps going into detail what I want from it: "I don't necessarily want to highlight things with a magnifying glass, like in the example. Zooming in might be nice.. ". If I don't know how to turn the video into gif myself, it might be worth mentioning that I want the video in gif format as well. And I'd personally want the video in a lossless video format as well as a gif, because once you go gif, you don't go back.

Comment: If you want to implement them in the app itself I suggest using a video instead of a gif since gif's are very limited.

Comment: I think I need some clarification: I need to place these images at the top of my sent of onboarding emails. Each covers a different topic. Example above would be for search. Naturally a video is not what I am looking for. I am looking at fiverr for instance. Difficult to find the right keywords to search for as they go for video explainers which indeed have sound and go on for a minute or so. Thanks again.

Comment: The included demo is also an *illustration*, not the app itself. Are you wanting it to be an illustration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes. It is *literally* an animated gif.**

The person you are hiring to make them should certainly understand they need to deliver an animated gif since, like all things, there is a set workflow required to produce one.

I would stay away from the term "explainer video" in this instance, which, at least to me, suggests this style: [Twitter explainer video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U8vlhMSVnJQ) - which is a roughly two minute long introduction/explaination to an app/concept, usually animated and with a voice over (and some cheesy music).

Of course simply saying "Hi, I need an animated gif" is not going to cover it! So perhaps the following sums it up as neatly as I can think:

**Suggested (micro) brief**

> I need a series of animated gifs, each a few seconds long, depicting
>   sections of my app UI in use, so that end-users can visually
>   appreciate how various interactions work.
>
> One example might be selecting various values from forms and running a
>   search.
>
> I attach an example, which illustrates the length and style I require

(Then you'd attach the animated gif above)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you see my clarification above? I am looking for a proper search term for this kind of image.

Comment: Hi, yes, but I really don't think there is a single "term" for it. If there is a term, then it's "animated gif" since that is what it is. I really believe the only way to explain what you want to a provider here is more or less as I suggested. Some things just don't have specific terminology.

Comment: https://www.pinterest.com/pin/43417583884839985/ shows "animated gifs of UI interactions" which I suppose is a further reduction, and might be a "term"

Comment: After nearly 300 views by presumably a fair amount of professionals, it's apparent that there is no definite "name" for this style. Therefore your best way forwards is to describe what you are looking for in as few words as it takes to make it clear, and to proffer examples.

Comment: Are you trying to look for a describing term so that somebody can make one for you? If so as for the output there really isn't going to be a term other than animated gif. If I was hiring a professional ui designer to make what you posted above. I would ask for a ui (user interface) animation.  After Effects, Flinto or Principle are three of many popular pieces of software people use to make animated gifs like the one you posted above.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to look for a describing term so that somebody can make one for you? If so as for the output there really isn't going to be a term other than animated gif. If I was hiring a professional ui designer to make what you posted above. I would ask for a ui (user interface) animation.  After Effects, Flinto or Principle are three of many popular pieces of software people use to make animated gifs like the one you posted above. This website will show you animations like the one you posted and will also tell you the software used to make the animation and I am sure you could reach out to a designer there for some paid help: Uplabs.com

Answer (score 0):

I would ask for a video 'product demo for my app' or 'video tour of my app' or 'video feature tour' and, as @joonas has mentioned, try to avoid animated GIFs as this format is limited. Some inspiration [here](https://campaignmonitor.com/features/) and [here](https://mailchimp.com/features/), these can be sent as examples to your provider.

Answer (score 0):

I think an illustrator/animator would understand that this is a "cartoon" representation of the app, as opposed to screenshot/screengrab, photo-realistic, or other representation. Another way to describe it would be to say an "abstracted representation of the app, showing animated actions like making a menu choice."

Answer (score 0):

It's simply animation work.

Based on what you are looking for, I'd use "animated tour of our application"

Answer (score 0):

I would call it animated... graphic.
Probably animated image... I know.

Let me complement, animated flat style image.

That animated image can be delivered as an animated GIF, but that is only the file format. It can be delivered as a CSS animation, CSS sprite animation, JavaScript based animation, canvas animation, or video. [This](https://media.giphy.com/media/X4Eh7IlSHrFx6/giphy.gif) is also an animated GIF and is nothing like the one you provided, so "animated GIF" is not the best term.

Answer (score 0):

It's animated graphics or motion graphics.
And you need an animation designer.
He/she is going to provide you the best format for your cause.
Probably the best format is video, then animated SVG and then the worst from many aspects animated Gifs.